# calling subset of an array to calculate autocorrelations in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to calculate an array's auto-correlation so need to access two subsets of the array (one with a lag) . Here's my code:

Option Base 1

```
Sub test()

Dim intPerNum As Integer
intPerNum = 10
Dim dblMRet() As Double
ReDim dblMRet(intPerNum)
Dim intPerCntr As Integer

Rnd (-2)
For intPerCntr = 1 To intPerNum
    dblMRet(intPerCntr) = WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Rnd(1))
    Range("TesterTest").Offset(0, intPerCntr) = dblMRet(intPerCntr) 'for debugging
Next intPerCntr

With WorksheetFunction
  Range("Output") = .Covar(.Index(dblMRet,0,1):.Index(dblMRet,0,intPerNum-1),.Index(dblMRet,0,2):.Index(dblMRet,0,intPerNum)) / .Var(dblMRet)
End With

End Sub
```

I can't use ":" to access a subset of the dblMRet array in VBA so that line does not work. What's a good way of doing this instead?  I do not want to make this calculation on an Excel worksheet since I do not want to output the array's actual values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/how-to-access-subset-of-an-array-in-excel-vba/c74765e5-b57e-423f-b9d4-0935ef9674e3?tm=1379435289782

Instead of using ":" in VBA, you can accomplish the same thing by using Evaluate inside the Index function. Works beautifully.

If you need to use variables inside Evaluate, you can just concatenate strings by using &.

For example, instead of using:

Range("Output") = WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Index(MyArray, 1, Evaluate("ROW(1:3)")))

I can use:

Range("Output") = WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Index(MyArray, 1, Evaluate("ROW(1:" &(intPerNum-1) &")")))